# Tab Bar Controller - エラー Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

プログラミング初心者です。Tab Bar Controllerについて質問があります。

私が使っているのはXcode Version 8.1、Swiftです。

カウントダウンタイマーとTo Do Listを別々のプロジェクトで作り終わり、その二つのアプリを一つのアプリにまとめたいと思っています。
新しいプロジェクトを作り、Tab Bar Controllerを使いながら二つのアプリをもう一度作り直していったのですが、シミュレーターを起動させると

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

という赤いエラーがAppDelegateの

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

に発生し、シミュレーターが止まります。
エラーの説明のようなものには

```
> 2017-01-06 19:55:12.188 PP Final Product[60637:3223775] Unknown class PomodoroViewController in Interface Builder file.
2017-01-06 19:55:12.571 PP Final Product[60637:3223775] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7fddcff03760> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key lbTimer.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010242734b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000101e8821e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102427299 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010199826f -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 291
    4   UIKit                               0x00000001029e44ef -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 88
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000102c5879e -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001023cc590 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 256
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000102c57122 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1867
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001029eac21 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 386
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001029eb543 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001029eb878 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 201
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001029ec0cc -[UIViewController view] + 27
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000102a4a2df -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 483
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000102a49721 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 59
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000102a455e2 -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 365
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000102a45464 -[UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:] + 234
    16  UIKit                               0x00000001029036e6 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 90
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000102a3fa00 -[UITabBarController _selectDefaultViewControllerIfNecessaryWithAppearanceTransitions:] + 354
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000102a40b7a -[UITabBarController viewWillAppear:] + 206
    19  UIKit                               0x00000001029f1a0f -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 692
    20  UIKit                               0x00000001029f211f -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 147
    21  UIKit                               0x00000001029f3913 -[UIViewController viewWillMoveToWindow:] + 507
    22  UIKit                               0x00000001028fa151 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _willMoveToWindow:withAncestorView:] + 621
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010290acf0 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 451
    24  UIKit                               0x00000001028f97a1 -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 838
    25  UIKit                               0x00000001028b5f5b -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 849
    26  UIKit                               0x00000001028b63a2 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 293
    27  UIKit                               0x00000001028c9cb5 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    28  UIKit                               0x0000000102842c89 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4818
    29  UIKit                               0x0000000102848de9 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1731
    30  UIKit                               0x0000000102845f69 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    31  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000106238723 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    32  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010623859c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 189
    33  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000106238925 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001023cc311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001023b159c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001023b0a86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001023b0494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    38  UIKit                               0x00000001028447e6 -[UIApplication _run] + 434
    39  UIKit                               0x000000010284a964 UIApplicationMain + 159
    40  PP Final Product                    0x000000010189782f main + 111
    41  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000105aa168d start + 1
    42  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

と書かれているのですが、いまいち理解できません。同じような質問をされている方がたくさんいたので、その解決方法（connectionを確認する、再起動する、など）をすべて試してみたのですが、直りませんでした。

問題はなんなのでしょうか？
また、Tab Bar Controllerの使い方や、複数のアプリを一つにまとめる方法は合っていますでしょうか？

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    internal var window: UIWindow?

    private var myTabBarController: UITabBarController!

    private func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?)
-> Bool {

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        let myFirstTab: UIViewController = PomodoroViewController()
        let mySecondTab: UIViewController = ToDoListViewController()

        let myTabs = NSArray(objects: myFirstTab, mySecondTab)

        myTabBarController = UITabBarController()

        myTabBarController?.setViewControllers(myTabs as? [UIViewController], animated: false)

        self.window!.rootViewController = myTabBarController

        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    } }
```

PomodoroViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class PomodoroViewController: UIViewController {

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

        self.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: UITabBarSystemItem.featured, tag: 1)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    required override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle!) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var lbTimer: UILabel!

    let pomodoroTime: TimeInterval = 60 * 25

    let formatter = DateFormatter()

    var theTime: TimeInterval = 0.0

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        formatter.dateFormat = "mm:ss"

        let startTime = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: pomodoroTime)
        lbTimer.text = formatter.string(from: startTime)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning(){
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func countDown(_ sender: UIButton) {

        theTime = pomodoroTime
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0,
                             target: self,
                             selector: #selector(PomodoroViewController.tickTimer(timer:)),
                             userInfo: nil,
                             repeats: true)
    }

    func tickTimer(timer: Timer){

        theTime -= 1.0
        let newTime = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: theTime)
        lbTimer.text = formatter.string(from: newTime)

        if theTime < 0.1 {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
     }
```

ToDoListViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ToDoListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, AddToDoItemControllerDelegate {

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

        self.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: UITabBarSystemItem.featured, tag: 2)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    required override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle!) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var toDoList: NSMutableArray = ["Go get groceries", "Walk the dog", "Watch a movie", "Do your homework"]

    var completedToDoList: [Int:String] = [:]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        resetAccessoryType()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return toDoList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ToDoCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = toDoList[indexPath.row] as? String

        return cell
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func resetAccessoryType() {
        for row in 0..<toDoList.count {
            if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)) {
                cell.accessoryType = .none
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            if cell.accessoryType == .none {
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
                completedToDoList[completedToDoList.count] = toDoList[indexPath.row] as? String
                toDoList.removeObject(at: indexPath.row)
            } else {
                cell.accessoryType = .none
            }
        }
    }

    func addToDoItemToList(_ text:String) {
        toDoList[toDoList.count] = text

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "AddToDoItemSegue") {
            let navigationController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
            let addToDoItemViewController = navigationController.topViewController as! AddToDoItemController

            addToDoItemViewController.delegate = self
        } else if(segue.identifier == "CompletedToDoItemsSegue") {
            let completedToDoItemsController = segue.destination as! CompletedToDoItemsController
            completedToDoItemsController.completedToDoList = completedToDoList
        }
    }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppDelegate.swiftに記述しているコードは、Storyboardなしでプロジェクトを構成するときのもので、Storyboardを使ったプロジェクトでは記述しません。プロジェクト作成時に戻しましょう。
アプリケーション起動時、Storyboardはどうやってロードされるのか説明します。プロジェクト設定のGeneralを開くと、次の箇所があります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
このMain Interfaceに入力した名称のStoryboardが、起動時ロードされます。デフォルトでは、Main.storyboardがロードされます。余談ですが、Storyboardなしのプロジェクトにするときは、ここを空にします。

---

次に、Storyboardに`UITabBarController`を導入する方法を説明します。手っ取り早いのは、プロジェクト作成時に、Tabbed Applicationのテンプレートから作成することです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

そうでない場合は、Object LibraryからTab Bar Controllerをドラッグ＆ドロップします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Storyboardの編集では、Storyboardで最初にロードされるView Controllerが何かを、まず意識することです。最初にロードするView Controllerを、Storyboardでは、**Initial View Controller**と呼びます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

View Controllerの左側に、矢印がついて、それがInitial View Controllerであることを示しています。View ControllerのAttributes Inspectorの「Is Initial View Controller」にチェックをつけることで、Initial View Controllerを変更することができます。現時点で、`UITabBarController`がInitial View Controllerになっていなければ、変更してください。

---

`UITabBarController`のタブに、View Controllerを追加するには、右ボタン＋ドラッグ（Controlキー＋ドラッグ）で、Tab Bar ControllerとView Controllerを結びます。ダイアログで、Relationship Segue、view controllersを選びます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ここで注意してもらいたいことは、ToDoListのように、`UINavigationController`によって画面遷移する一連のView Controllerは、Tab Bar Controllerと、Navigation Controllerをつなぐという点です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

そうしないと、画面遷移が機能しなくなります。

---

*この回答は、質問者さんのレスポンスによって、内容を更新していく予定にしています。*

Comment: Storyboardについての説明を書いておらず申し訳ございません。
私はStoryboardを使ってアプリを作っています。Storyboardでコントローラーを繋げた時は、コードにしてファイルに書く必要がないのですね。
一度、コントローラーをstoryboardで繋げただけでシミュレーターを起動したところ、エラーが出てきて同じようにシミュレーターが動かなかったので、tab bar controller用にコードを書く必要があるのかと思い書きました。
だとすると、問題点は他のところにあるのですね。赤い注意マークは一つも出ていないのですが、他に問題点はありますでしょうか？

Comment: @miki_ninn 回答を更新しました。

Answer (score 0):

重要な1行が追加されたので、原因はほぼ特定できたという感じですが、またstoryboardの設定の問題ですね。

> ```
> 2017-01-06 19:55:12.188 PP Final Product[60637:3223775] Unknown class PomodoroViewController in Interface Builder file.
> ```

このエラーが発生するのは、storyboardに設定してある`PomodoroViewController`と言うクラス名が、アプリの実行時にはシステム側からは見えない(よってUnknown)状態になっていることを表しています。

この状態が発生すると、iOSはとりあえずプレーンな`UIViewController`をインスタンス化するため`lbTimer`と言う`@IBOutlet`をつなぎに行った時に、そんなものは`UIViewController`にはないので、*this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key lbTimer.* と言う次の行のエラー(例外)につながるわけです。

一度`@IBOutlet`の接続に成功した状態ならそんな不整合は発生しては困るのですが、残念ながら現在のXcodeでは、storyboardとソースコードの編集を交互に行っていたりすると、ちょくちょく発生します。とりあえず再度storyboardの設定を確認してみてください。

`PomodoroViewController`を設定してあるはずのViewControllerをstoryboardエディター内で選択し、Inspector部分で以下の内容を確認してください。

[image: CustomClass設定]

上段の**Class**はもちろん`PomodoroViewController`になっていないといけないのですが、下段の**Module**も上の図のように`Current - {あなたのプロジェクト名}`になっていないといけません。Storyboardで不整合が発生していると、見かけ上は正しく設定されているように見えても内部的におかしいと言うこともあるので、一旦設定を削除してから設定し直したほうがいいかもしれません。

---

ちなみにAppDelegate.swift内のこのコードはiOS側から呼ばれることはありません。

```
private func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?)　-> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let myFirstTab: UIViewController = PomodoroViewController()
    let mySecondTab: UIViewController = ToDoListViewController()

    let myTabs = NSArray(objects: myFirstTab, mySecondTab)

    myTabBarController = UITabBarController()

    myTabBarController?.setViewControllers(myTabs as? [UIViewController], animated: false)

    self.window!.rootViewController = myTabBarController

    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

`private`を付けているので、このメソッドの存在はiOS側には見えなくなっています。なんの働きもしていませんから、まるごと削除してしまうといいでしょう。将来アプリを拡張する場合に困ることもあるので、代わりに新規プロジェクトを作成した時にできるこのメソッドを入れておいてもいいかもしれません。

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

(メソッドヘッダーで`_`の有無や`launchOptions`のデータ型が異なっているのに注意してください。後者がSwift 3での正しい`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`メソッドの書き方になります。)

---

他にもまだ何かあるかもしれませんが、とりあえず上記のstoryboardの設定確認をしてみてください。